# Why is my child class(ES5 OOP) not running on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, oop, ecmascript-5

The problem is when I click the button with id squareBtn it does not run the Square class. I select the button that creates the shape class the same way and it works just fine. I have an alert in my child square class and that isn't even running. I'm aware this is probably something dumb, but I can't find the solution so I am coming here for help so please have mercy.

```js
class Shape {
  constructor() {
    this.div = $('<div class="position-absolute"></div>');
    this.positioning();
    $(this.div).css('background-color', allHSLAcolors[randomNumber(0, 360)]);
    $(this.div).dblclick(() => this.div.remove());
    $('#container').append(this.div);
  }
  positioning() {
    $(this.div).css('top', randomNumber(0, 400) + "px");
    $(this.div).css('left', randomNumber(0, 100) + "%");
  }
}

class Square extends Shape {
  constructor() {
    this.length = $('#square').val();
    $(this.div).css('height', this.length + 'px');
    $(this.div).css('width', this.length + 'px');
    alert('hi');
  }
}

$('#hey').on('click', () => new Shape);
$('#squareBtn').on('click', () => new Square);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <button id="squareBtn" class="btn mx-1 btn-primary" for="square">Square</button>
  <input id="square" type="number" placeholder="Length">
</div>
```

Comment: `new Shape Square` is invalid syntax. I think you mean `new Square`

Comment: Didn't you see the syntax error in the console?

Comment: I don't know why I had that it isn't like that in my actual code I have new Sqaure

Comment: Console has no errors it just isn't running

Comment: After fixing that, there's an error saying that the subclass has to call the superclass constructor.

Comment: When I click on your Square button it says: **Uncaught ReferenceError: Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor**

Comment: @Barmar that's really weird that mine doesen't. Could I need to change a setting or something?

Comment: If you put the alert at the beginning of the constructor, do you see it?

Comment: Yes the alert comes up, the square is generated, and then it disappears. The square also does this behavior if I remove the alert altogether. I am just using the alert for testing purposes.

Comment: Is the button inside a `<form>` in your real page? If so, it's submitting the form, which reloads the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's just `new Square`.

```
$('#squareBtn').on('click', () => new Square);
```

2. You need to call `super` in the constructor.

```
class Square extends Shape {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: That's already fixed, it was a copying error.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! The code works now, but the generated Square disappears immediately after its creation. Any ideas?

Comment: `<button type="button id="squareBtn"`

Comment: Oh my god... How does the type of button on the button element change that behavior on the div????????

Comment: @Wayne By default, the button will submit the form it is in.